# Log in craigslist account and redirected into Home page by curl

Tags: curl, authentication, craigslist

Here is my code :

```
$username="####################"; 
$password="######################"; 

$loginUrl = 'https://accounts.craigslist.org/login/';

//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Set the post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'inputEmailHandle='.$username.'&inputPassword='.$password);

//Handle cookies for the login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

//Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
//not to print out the results of its query.
//Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
//from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute the request (the login)
$store = curl_exec($ch);

//the login is now done and you can continue to get the
//protected content.

//set the URL to the protected file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.craigslist.org/login/home');

//execute the request
$content = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);
```

Its not working.Please suggest what to do so that it can be redirected to home page after being logged in.

Any kind of help and appreciation will be appreciated.

Comment: What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: @  rozkosz : When i am echoing $content its showing 404 error page